# What are some techniques to facilitate safe refactoring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm coming from statically typed languages like C++ where there are tools (the compiler for one) that will remind me if I forget something obvious while refactoring. For example, if I change the number of arguments to a function but I forget to change all the calls to it. But it seems really easy to make this type of mistake in javascript. How do you avoid problems like this when refactoring javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like you do in c++/java.  By writing tests.

Unit tests are the best.  If you code is MVC, then you can certainly have unit tests with little effort, at least for the model layer.  The benefit is you get feedback immediately.  Check out  [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)

Functional tests via Selenium or equivalent are good too.  They will find problems, but not immediately.

Comment: I have tests. But taking the example I mentioned above (which was just one example) do you write tests that explicitly check the number of arguments to a function and fail if it changes? That only reminds you that you changed the function. I'm still not sure I would now if there is a call to that function somehwere in my code that calls with the wrong arguments but still just happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing like that I can think of is: JSLint (http://jslint.com/)